# How to add Report Server Project template to VS2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008, reporting-services

Report Service Project template is only available in VS 2008 when install SQL Server 2008.

Even VS 2010 utilmate have no this template. How to add it to VS 2010?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot. VS 2010 doesn't have BIDS and therefore you cannot create SSRS reports in VS 2010. You'll have to use VS 2008 (as I do) or use Report Builder 2 or 3.

I have been told that once SQL Server 'Denali' is released, BIDS will be added to VS 2010.